# TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to do some mathematical calculation according to the values at particular index of a NumPy array with the following code

```
X = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
temp = X.copy().fill(5.446361E-01)
ind = np.where(X < 4.0)
temp[ind] = 0.5*X[ind]**2 - 1.0
ind = np.where(X >= 4.0 and X < 9.0)
temp[ind] = (5.699327E-1*(X[ind]-1)**4)/(X[ind]**4)
print temp
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
temp[ind] = 0.5*X[ind]**2 - 1.0 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Would you please help me in solving this?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`fill`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.fill.html) return nothing.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> temp = X.copy()
>>> return_value_of_fill = temp.fill(5.446361E-01)
>>> return_value_of_fill is None
True
```

Replace following line:

```
temp = X.copy().fill(5.446361E-01)
```

with:

```
temp = X.copy()
temp.fill(5.446361E-01)
```

Comment: now it is showing the following error --  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: @RSJohn, Replace `ind = np.where(X >= 4.0 and X < 9.0)` with `ind = np.where((X >= 4.0) & (X < 9.0))`